# Plotting multiple graphs in the same window

Tags: gnuplot

I'd like to plot (splot) 2 objects from c++ code in the same window with 2 gnuplot calls. Meaning not both at the same time like `splot obj1, obj2` but with 2 gnuplot scripts.
Is that possible and how ?

The reason is that I'll make different scripts for different types of object1 (4 types) which needs different set of parameters and same with object2 (2 types). So I'll call `gnuplot -e ARG=... -e ARG2=... gp_scritp_object1_type2`.
and then the same with object2 ... but they need to be in the same window.
Not sure I'm clear here...

Thanks anyway.

Comment: No, I think it is not possible. Maybe you can work with one main script, which uses `call` to load the different sub scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Christoph, got it working with the very hacky

```
call OBJ1 P0 P1 P2 P3 P4 P5 P5 P7 P8 P9
call OBJ2 P20 P21 P22 P23 P24 P25 P26 P27 P28 P29
```

in main script, where OBJ1 and OBJ2 are script filenames pointing to different types of obj1 and obj2, each taking different set of parameters.

Thankfully, the 9 parameters don't need to be all defined. Downside is I only have up to 9 parameters... But that will do for now.

Comment: If the 9 parameters aren't enough, you can set some variables in the main script, which are available in the called script as well. Consider the script call.gp which contains only `print myvar`. Then in gnuplot use `myvar = 1; call 'call.gp'`. A variable may also contain whitespace-separated string, which can be accessed with the `word` function: `str="aaa bbb ccc"; print word(str, 1)`. Maybe that helps you.